# "Он убедится, я — ..?"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Есть форма первого лица единственного числа и будущего времени у глагола "убедиться"? То есть, "он убедится, а я —..?"

Answer (score 2):

Позволю себе скопировать интересную заметку, хотя она и не является прямым ответом.

Я тебя убедю, убежу или убежду?  
11.02.2010 11:57
Как правило, все личные формы могут быть образованы от абсолютного большинства глаголов: читаю, смотрю, говорю и т.д. Иногда при образовании форм первого лица наблюдается чередование звуков: стыдить - стыжу, косить - кошу, пылесосить - пылесошу.
Но есть ряд трудных глаголов, на которых спотыкается любой, кто захочет образовать от них форму первого лица настоящего времени. От глагола победить - победю или побежу, от глагола колесить - колесю или колешу? По той или иной причине от них нельзя образовать формы 1-го лица единственного числа настоящего или будущего времени.  
Что же мешает? 
Есть три группы препятствий. Первая: некоторые глаголы не могут быть связаны с представлением о человеке и его деятельности: плодоносить, телиться, окотиться и др. Нельзя сказать: я плодоносю, телюсь.
Вторая: некоторые глаголы просто не имеют формы 1-го лица: галдеть, убедить, победить, шкодить и др. 
Ещё в начале XX века от глаголов убедить, победить справочники рекомендовали обе формы: убедю и убежу, победю и побежу. Теперь они остались только в ненормативной лексике. У Владимира Высоцкого встречаем: "А принцессу мне и даром не надо, чуду-юду я и так победю".
А как быть, если всё-таки действие подобных глаголов надо адресовать себе? Литературный язык рекомендует использовать в этом случае описательные обороты: "Я постараюсь убедить, надеюсь победить, не смогу надерзить".  
Третья причина: иногда совпадают формы 1-го лица по звучанию и написанию от разных по смыслу глаголов: от глагола будить - бужу и от глагола бузить - бужу; от глагола держать - держу и от дерзить - держу;  от ладить - лажу и от лазить - лажу. В каждой такой паре один глагол является ущербным и в русской речи не употребляется. Мы не говорим: "Я держу этому человеку" (от глагола дерзить). Лучше сказать: "Я стал дерзить этому человеку", или "Я надерзил ему…"

Галина ШЕПЕЛЕВА,
профессор КРСУ

http://delo.kg/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=683&catid=49:2011-05-19-20-39-11&Itemid=116

Comment: Хорошо, что есть ссылка: посмотрю и убежусь ;-)) 

И правда, как будто бежать куда-то собираюсь!

Comment: Я сегодня тугодмлю слегка.
Вы мне дерзите или наезжаете? 
А то ведь я и в ответ надерзю и наездю.
И окотюсь напоследок.

Comment: Что Вы, я бы не посмела! Шучу просто, каламбурю. А хотите наехать - пожалуйста, чай, вы не каток, вытерплю! ;-))  

Я бы вообще сказала, что считаю себя Вашим другом, если бы еще раньше мы не выяснили, что дружба - понятие взаимное.

Comment: Я от того не отказываюсь, просто дружба в вирте для меня "вещь в себе". Любовь марионеток. Театр Брехта.
ЗЫ Я тоже шутю. Здесь и рашьше. Уж больно слова понравились. "Убежусь" на моё ухо звучит вполне премлемо.

Answer (score 0):

Глагол "убедиться" не имеет формы 1 лица единственного числа. Норма зафиксирована в орфоэпических словарях, например, в словаре Т.Ф. Ивановой "Новый орфоэпический словарь русского языка", М. Дрофа, 2008.

Answer (score 0):

При необходимости сказать фразу от первого лица с глаголами "убедить, победить" в этом случае употребляют описательную форму: "сумею убедить", "смогу победить", "постараюсь убедить" и т.п.