# "Ластиться" - спряжение

Tags: словоформы

Глагол **ластиться** тоже не имеет формы 1 лица ед. ч.? Интересно, сколько ещё подобных глаголов в русском языке (кроме *победить* и *убедить*)?

Answer (score 2):

Тоже - это плюс к разбиравшемуся "убедить"?
Я в том обсуждении [заметку скопировал](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/9946/%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%8F), в ней есть еще примеры (плодоносить, телиться, окотиться, галдеть, шкодить, дерзить и т.д.) и - главное - причины такого положения дел.

Но суть не в этом. Число таких глаголов постоянно меняется. Тот же "убедить" не так давно еще имел целых два варианта формы "1л ед.ч". С другой стороны "пылесошу" стало нормативным тоже недавно. Поймать точное число не представляется возможным. 
Думаю, число тагих глаголов (считая только словарные бесприставочные) не превышает пяти  десятков (с большим запасом), но их число будет скорее расти, чем сокращаться.

Answer (score 0):

"Лащусь" - это более приемлемо, чем "дужу" или "дерзю". Вполне нормальная форма 1л ед.ч. Не понятно, почему метка "спряжение" ?

Comment: А какая метка должна быть?